# Is it a good idea to call PUT from POST method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, post, put

I have to automate certain operations of PUT/POST operation in my case, I have those endpoints already-in-place which will do their part.

My planning is to have another method which will drive this whole automation, consider this method as new POST endpoint which would gonna call each either POST and PUT endpoint from the same service which I already mentioned.

I will gonna call those existing PUT and POST based on input, if consider the input is new I will call existing POST and if given input exists in database I will going to call PUT.

Till I am good, But I have a question in my mind, Which is bugging me a lot that my new endpoint which is of POST is calling PUT as well as POST, I each method type has to do its type of operations only but here I am calling PUT as well as POST whereas my parent calling method type is POST.

I am not sure if I am working in right direction to achieve my use-case.

Please correct me in a different way.

Note - I am having Spring Boot application which would always need some endpoint to trigger any logic which I am talking about.

Update my question for better understanding.

Comment: I don't understand your use case exactly, but...
If you want to check if an entry already exists, use GET or HEAD to make it explicit. If you just want an entry to be existant, use PUT as it would either create a new or replace an existing entry.

Comment: update the question @lathspell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont really know what you mean exactly. The HTTP methods are considered to do a specific task, but yet again its ok to use POST to update something - might be not best practice, but works. If you want to seperate the concerns (adding, updating), then just implement two different endpoints, one handling the creation the other one the update. The client (whether its a web-app or desktop app or whatever) has to handle this issue.

Comment: That's what I wanted to say too, the client-side has to handle the issue of selecting the PUT or POST method.

Comment: so you are saying that I should not have to write another method in the same service but I should have to write the same logic into another Client-side code like calling my API endpoints from some python code also in the add on I can operation some other operations as well.

Comment: Your API should be loosely coupled with anything. Means you have two endpoints, one for creating one for updating. You expose a documentation about your API defining which endpoints you have and what they need. The client has to implement the calls according to ur API docs. If you are implementing the client urself, you know what endpoints you have and what their purpose is. If you have the same logic consider DRY and create a function that is shared within ur client-services